# New Tab for PageReference

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, controller, pagereference

I want to open my Vf page on new tab please guide me what i need to do to get the process done my code :

```
 public PageReference totalbookedClick(){
     date myDate = date.today();
    integer thisyear = myDate.year();
     PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/TotalBookedPage?contact= {!'+cntMap.keyset()+'}&End_Date={!'+thisyear+'}&Start_Date={!'+thisyear+'}');
     return pageRef ;
```

Vf page

```
           <apex:form > 
           <apex:commandLink value="{!LB}" action="{!totalbookedClick}" />
           </apex:form>
```

please guide me what else need to do get it working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be able to add a target attribute:-

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!LB}" action="{!totalbookedClick}" target="_blank"/>
```

Comment: Remember SFDC have created docs! http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm

Comment: Richard Durrant, those were not working in IE and if they were inside a iframe

Answer (score 0):

To do this using JS directly in the VF page

```
 function openInNewTab(){
     var date = new Date();
     var thisyear = date.getFullYear();
     var url = '/apex/TotalBookedPage?contact={!cntMap.keyset()}&End_Date=' + thisyear + '&Start_Date=' + thisyear;
     window.open(url,'_blank');
 }
 <apex:commandLink value="{!LB}" onclick="openInNewTab();" />
```